# On which points of $xy=(1-x-y)^2$ is the tangent parallel to the $x$-axis?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

> On which points of $xy=(1-x-y)^2$ is the tangent  parallel to the $x$-axis?

All I get is the derivative of the function, as far I know, I set the derivative equals to zero.

Comment: That sounds about right.

Comment: But I don't know how to proceed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tangent line is parallel to the $x$-axis, then $y' = 0$.

We can determine when $y' = 0$ by differentiating the equation

$$xy = (1 - x - y)^2$$

implicitly with respect to $x$, which yields

\begin{align*}
y + xy' & = 2(1 - x - y)(-1 - y')\\
y + xy' & = -2(1 - x - y) - 2(1 - x - y)y'\\
xy' + 2(1 - x - y)y' & = -2(1 - x - y) - y\\
(x + 2 - 2x - 2y)y' & = -2 + 2x + 2y - y\\
(2 - x - 2y)y' & = -2 + 2x + y\\
y' & = \frac{-2 + 2x + y}{2 - x - 2y}
\end{align*}
which is equal to $0$ when $y = 2 - 2x$.

Substituting $2 - 2x$ for $y$ in the original equation yields

\begin{align*}
x(2 - 2x) & = [1 - x - (2 - 2x)]^2\\
2x - 2x^2 & = (-1 + x)^2\\
2x - 2x^2 & = 1 - 2x + x^2\\
0 & = 3x^2 - 4x + 1\\
  & = 3x^2 - 3x - x - 1\\
  & = 3x(x - 1) - 1(x - 1)\\
  & = (3x - 1)(x - 1) 
\end{align*}

Thus, $y' = 0$ when $x = 1$ or $x = 1/3$.  If $x = 1$, then $y = 2 - 2x = 0$.  If $x = 1/3$, then $y = 2 - 2x = 4/3$.  Hence, the curve $xy = (1 - x - y)^2$ has horizontal tangents at the points $(1, 0)$ and $(1/3, 4/3)$.

Comment: Yes! This is right, thank you!